# DriveClient and DriveResourceClient always throwing FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-api-java-client

I got a successful `GoogleSignInAccount` object, and I need to get both DriveClient and DriveResourceClient of this account, I'm actualy doing in this way:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

if(account != null){

  DriveClient driveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this,account);

  DriveResourceClient driveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this,account);

}
```

But, when I try to perform simple tasks like:

```
DriveFolder root = driveResourceClient.getRootFolder().getResult();
```

I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.myorg.myapp, PID: 21980
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myorg.myapp/com.myorg.myapp.DriveUpload2}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
>           at com.myorg.myapp.DriveUpload2.signIn(DriveUpload2.java:94)
>           at com.myorg.myapp.DriveUpload2.onCreate(DriveUpload2.java:139)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6406)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

All scope configurations on Google Console Credentials page are correct, and required scope like `Drive.SCOPE_FILE` and `Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER` have already been requested during the creation of `GoogleSignInOptions`.